# Elasticsearch result from Python client not parsed as json object by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, elasticsearch

I am unable to create a Javascript object from the Elasticsearch(2.1.1) response I get from my Python (2.7) client.

Python code:

```
es=Elasticsearch();
@app.route('/output')
def findSpots():
    lat = request.args.get('lati')
    lon = request.args.get('longi')
    res=es.search(index="park_reg", doc_type="parksgn",body={"from": 0, "size": 1, "query": {"filtered": {"filter":  {"geo_distance":  {"distance": "500km","location": {"lat":lat,"lon":lon}}}}}})

return render_template("output.html",lat=lat,lon=lon, res=json.dumps(res))
```

Javascript code:

```
var res = "{{res}}";
console.log(typeof(res)); //Gives string
document.write(res);
document.write("</br>")
document.write("</br>")

//Tried this as JSON.parse(res) was giving an error
var resStr =JSON.stringify(res);
document.write(resStr);
document.write("</br>")
document.write("</br>")

var resJSON = JSON.parse(resStr);
document.write(resJSON);
```

Response:

```
{"hits": {"hits": [{"_score": 1.0, "_type": "parksgn", "_id": "13452823", "_source": {"canParkDays": [""], "x": 965522.6237, "seqnum": 5, "ordernum": "P-087419", "signdesc": "2 HOUR PARKING 9AM-7PM EXCEPT SUNDAY", "canParkDuration": -1, "noParkDays": [""], "SG_MUTCD_C": "R7-182R", "signfc": "", "canParkTime": [""], "location": {"lat": "40.591472", "lon": "-74.06743"}, "arrow": "", "canPark": "true", "y": 154772.6633, "distfromcurb": 310, "borough": "S", "noParkTime": [""], "id": 13452823}, "_index": "park_reg"}], "total": 376893, "max_score": 1.0}, "_shards": {"successful": 5, "failed": 0, "total": 5}, "took": 35, "timed_out": false}

"{"hits": {"hits": [{"_score": 1.0, "_type": "parksgn", "_id": "13452823", "_source": {"canParkDays": [""], "x": 965522.6237, "seqnum": 5, "ordernum": "P-087419", "signdesc": "2 HOUR PARKING 9AM-7PM EXCEPT SUNDAY", "canParkDuration": -1, "noParkDays": [""], "SG_MUTCD_C": "R7-182R", "signfc": "", "canParkTime": [""], "location": {"lat": "40.591472", "lon": "-74.06743"}, "arrow": "", "canPark": "true", "y": 154772.6633, "distfromcurb": 310, "borough": "S", "noParkTime": [""], "id": 13452823}, "_index": "park_reg"}], "total": 376893, "max_score": 1.0}, "_shards": {"successful": 5, "failed": 0, "total": 5}, "took": 35, "timed_out": false}"

{"hits": {"hits": [{"_score": 1.0, "_type": "parksgn", "_id": "13452823", "_source": {"canParkDays": [""], "x": 965522.6237, "seqnum": 5, "ordernum": "P-087419", "signdesc": "2 HOUR PARKING 9AM-7PM EXCEPT SUNDAY", "canParkDuration": -1, "noParkDays": [""], "SG_MUTCD_C": "R7-182R", "signfc": "", "canParkTime": [""], "location": {"lat": "40.591472", "lon": "-74.06743"}, "arrow": "", "canPark": "true", "y": 154772.6633, "distfromcurb": 310, "borough": "S", "noParkTime": [""], "id": 13452823}, "_index": "park_reg"}], "total": 376893, "max_score": 1.0}, "_shards": {"successful": 5, "failed": 0, "total": 5}, "took": 35, "timed_out": false}
```

I verified "res" is a valid JSON, but still it isn't working. "resJSON" also gives string.

Comment: if `res` is the response, try slicing it to `hits` key's values alone. You might have to replace `res`  here `json.dumps(res)` with `eval(res.replace("true","True").replace("false","False"))["hits"]["hits"]` which will be a dictionary.

Comment: the javascript snippet `var res = "{{res}}";` doesn't make sense you are explicitly assiging a string to res which is not valid JSON .

Comment: @keety : How should I access value of res ?

Comment: how do you invoke the python client from javascript code i would assume using something on lines of [getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)? You would need post the code snippet invoking the python api it would be easier to help

Comment: I'm using flask. I believe it handles it internally

Answer (score 0):

So this is what my response looked like on the console:

```
"{&#34;hits&#34;: {&#34;hits&#34;: [{&#34;_score&#34;: 1.0, &#34;_type&#34;: &#34;parksgn&#34;, &#34;_id&#34;: &#34;13452823&#34;, &#34;_source&#34;: {&#34;canParkDays&#34;: [&#34;&#34;], &#34;x&#34;: 965522.6237, &#34;seqnum&#34;: 5, &#34;ordernum&#34;: &#34;P-087419&#34;, &#34;signdesc&#34;: &#34;2 HOUR PARKING 9AM-7PM EXCEPT SUNDAY&#34;, &#34;canParkDuration&#34;: -1, &#34;noParkDays&#34;: [&#34;&#34;], &#34;SG_MUTCD_C&#34;: &#34;R7-182R&#34;, &#34;signfc&#34;: &#34;&#34;, &#34;canParkTime&#34;: [&#34;&#34;], &#34;location&#34;: {&#34;lat&#34;: &#34;40.591472&#34;, &#34;lon&#34;: &#34;-74.06743&#34;}, &#34;arrow&#34;: &#34;&#34;, &#34;canPark&#34;: &#34;true&#34;, &#34;y&#34;: 154772.6633, &#34;distfromcurb&#34;: 310, &#34;borough&#34;: &#34;S&#34;, &#34;noParkTime&#34;: [&#34;&#34;], &#34;id&#34;: 13452823}, &#34;_index&#34;: &#34;park_reg&#34;}], &#34;total&#34;: 376893, &#34;max_score&#34;: 1.0}, &#34;_shards&#34;: {&#34;successful&#34;: 5, &#34;failed&#34;: 0, &#34;total&#34;: 5}, &#34;took&#34;: 18, &#34;timed_out&#34;: false}"
```

Just replacing &#34 with double quotes (") did the trick

```
var res = "{{res}}".split("&#34;").join("\"")
var resJSON = JSON.parse(res)
console.log(typeof(resJSON))
```